# Google Maps Error

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm hoping someone has come across this problem also.  I'm a newbie to all this, therefore excuse my lack of knowledge in advance.

I currently have Google Maps API setup on my wordpress site.  When I perform a search on the site i.e. page containing Google Map, no listing results are been found.  Upon further investigation I have been advised that:

there's a JS error on my website coming from Maps API. Chrome Dev Console shows:

> js?key=++AIzaSyC_GzbCPmMM8Jme9ZAi-IbKOdaXo_SfK_I+&libraries=places&ver=3b47f53……:34 InvalidValueError: setComponentRestrictions: not an Object

in source view of the page the google maps JS is called via this
https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=++AIzaSyC_GzbCPmMM8Jme9ZAi-IbKOdaXo_SfK_I+&libraries=places&ver=3b47f534942a304aaad0d1a98d2531f8

the part "&ver=3b47f534942a304aaad0d1a98d2531f8" shouldn't be there (it's added to each JS file), so we assume it must be coming from some plugin that I have that might be causing that issue.

Before I start disabling every plugin on my wordpress site, has anyone come across this error before?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Justin

Comment: Posting a [mcve] that exhibits the problem (your code) would be helpful.  Looks like the API is reporting an error in your inputs to one of the services.

Comment: https://github.com/ubilabs/geocomplete/issues/309#issuecomment-271791421

Comment: @redFIVE this thread currently appears to be the only result for this exact error on google.  I have also been experiencing this error within the last day or so, it seems to have come out of the blue. Will research further.

Comment: I am now experiencing this as well - this is the only relevant result in the SERPs

Comment: **InvalidValueError: setComponentRestrictions: not an Object** is occurring for me as well.  Just noticed it this morning.  Any possible change it's a Google thing?

Answer (score 8):

OK - so apparently this was a bug introduced in the 3.27 release of Google Maps.

https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=11253&q=setComponentRestrictions&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal

The Google team has it logged and is working on it.

In the meantime you can do as follows:

> Thanks for the report! We have created an internal ticket to investigate this.
>   On the meantime, you can load JavaScript API version 3.26 to avoid getting this error.

UPDATE: It does not look like they plan on fixing this.  So the correct fix would be to change your settings to:

```
autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': []});
```

Comment: I have the same error on 3.2.6. Fixed by completely avoiding the `setComponentRestrictions` call instead of passing `null` when I didn't need it

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem, but I have changed to the version 3 and it has worked. Obviously, that it isn't the best way to correct it, but I can use this solution up to somebody publishes the correct fix.

Before
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MyKey]&libraries=places

After
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[MyKey]&libraries=places&v=3

Answer (score 0):

I just started noticing a similar error as well, `InvalidValueError: setComponentRestrictions: in property country: not a string; and not an Array`. It turns out I was passing an empty object, `{}`, as the `componentRestrictions` option when trying to initialize a [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete).

It looks like that `componentRestrictions` option is used by the Google Maps API, you can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-component-restriction). I am assuming that Google recently made a change that throws an exception if it is configured wrong.

So in your particular case I imagine either you, or one of your plugins, is not setting `componentRestrictions` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade Google Maps to Version 3.28.